# Sending post using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, node.js

I have a node.js which waits for post with 2 parameters (name and pass):

```
app.post('/login.html', function (req, res) {

    log.info(req.body);
    userName = req.body.name;
    pass = req.body.pass;
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to send post with the 2 parameters via simple java application, but I can't see that it arrive to the node.js.

what am I missing ?

The java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://83.63.118.111:31011/login.html");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();               
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));          
        String str = "name='root'&pass='123456'";
        //System.out.print(str);
        writer.write(str);
        writer.flush();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        writer.close();
        os.close();       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will close when start send data (send and stop)

You should wait it done.

Add code after `writer.flush();`

Example get `response`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

or just get `responseCode`:

```
int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Your program wait send request success or fail.

I think you use `Thread.sleep(100);` to wait send request, but it stop your Thread (don't send data to server)

Your code have `req.body`, Express.js don't have it, need use middleware [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: I agree that sleeping is the wrong thing to do here (it usually is).  The program should instead affirmatively wait for the HTTP response, whether it reads the details or not.  Obtaining the response code is a good way to do that. (And how else could the client know whether the program was successful?)  It might, however, be necessary to close, not just flush, the connection's output stream prior to trying to obtain the response.

Comment: Now I see the post on the server, but is seems that req.body is empty. why ?

Comment: `req.body` is `undefined`. If you want have `req.body`, please use module `body-parser`